# Expand form based on radio selection in jQuery & Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a part of a form, based on the input of a visitor. Currently whenever I change the radio button value, it still keeps showing the the part of the form of the last selection made. What I want my form to do is, when the user changes the value of the `<input type="radio">` and when it just made a part of the form visible, to make it disappear again, since it is not required. I guess you can get the idea of what I want when I paste my code current code down here and see for yourself what is going wrong there:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[name="Selection"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'Selection-1')
    {
     $("#Selection-1-container").toggleClass('hidden');
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'Selection-2')
    {
     $("#Selection-2-container").toggleClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Selection">Selection</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="Selection-0">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-0" value="Value-1" checked="checked">
        When this one selected, neither 'Selection' of the code below.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="Selection-1">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-1" value="Value-2">
        When this one selected, show Selection-1 only.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="Selection-2">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-2" value="Value-3">
        When this one selected, show Selection-2 only.
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Selection-1-container" class="hidden">
  <h4>Selection 1</h4>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column1">Column1</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column1" name="Column1" type="text"
             placeholder="Column1" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column2">Column2</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column2" name="Column2" type="text"
             placeholder="Column2" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column3">Column3</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column3" name="Column3" type="text"
             placeholder="Column3" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column4">Column4</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column4" name="Column4" type="text"
             placeholder="Column4" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column5">Column5</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="Column5" name="Column5" required>
        <option value>Choose an option...</option>
        <option value>Option 1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Selection-2-container" class="hidden">
  <h4>Selection 2</h4>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column6">Column6</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column6" name="Column6" type="text"
             placeholder="Column6" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column7">Column7</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column7" name="Column7" type="text"
             placeholder="Column7" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column8">Column7</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column8" name="Column8" type="text"
             placeholder="Column8" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column9">Column9</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column9" name="Column9" type="text"
             placeholder="Column9" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column10">Column10</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="Column10" name="Column10" required>
        <option value>Choose an option...</option>
        <option value>Option 1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyone that can suggest what I should add (I assume to my javascript code) to make it work perfectly fine the way I intend this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class (like `togglehid`) to your elements that need to be hidden.
Then, if you click ***any*** checkbox, hide those classes. After that, one becomes visible.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[name="Selection"]').click(function() {

          $('.togglehid').addClass('hidden');
          // code changed here --> add the class hidden to all div's with class togglehid

       if($(this).attr('id') == 'Selection-1')
        {
         $("#Selection-1-container").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') == 'Selection-2')
        {
         $("#Selection-2-container").toggleClass('hidden');
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Selection">Selection</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="radio">
          <label for="Selection-0">
            <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-0" value="Value-1" checked="checked">
            When this one selected, neither 'Selection' of the code below.
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label for="Selection-1">
            <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-1" value="Value-2">
            When this one selected, show Selection-1 only.
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label for="Selection-2">
            <input type="radio" name="Selection" id="Selection-2" value="Value-3">
            When this one selected, show Selection-2 only.
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Selection-1-container" class="togglehid hidden">
    <!-- code changed here too, added the class -->


      <h4>Selection 1</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column1">Column1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column1" name="Column1" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column1" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column2">Column2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column2" name="Column2" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column2" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column3">Column3</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column3" name="Column3" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column3" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column4">Column4</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column4" name="Column4" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column4" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column5">Column5</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="Column5" name="Column5" required>
            <option value>Choose an option...</option>
            <option value>Option 1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Selection-2-container" class="togglehid hidden">
    <!-- code changed here too, added the class -->


      <h4>Selection 2</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column6">Column6</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column6" name="Column6" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column6" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column7">Column7</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column7" name="Column7" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column7" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column8">Column7</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column8" name="Column8" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column8" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column9">Column9</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Column9" name="Column9" type="text"
                 placeholder="Column9" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Column10">Column10</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="Column10" name="Column10" required>
            <option value>Choose an option...</option>
            <option value>Option 1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a decent solution and I will see if I can make something like this work. It looks kind of lame to have two same classes with exactly similar CSS though, so I wonder if there might be a better way to do this. I guess it comes down to resseting `#Selection-1-container` and `#Selection-2-container` to hidden after every click before running the `if` statement.

Comment: The reason I use one class to hide them, and different classes to show them, is because you dont want to code a `toggle` function for many classes. Its simply not readible. I prefer to use more classes at my HTML elements and use those groups of classes for my functions. That's what they are meant for (if you want unique class names, you should use the id instead)

Comment: Yes and I also noticed it would be possible to use multiple lines in JavaScript although this again, looks like repeating pieces of code: `$("#Bezorging-1-container").addClass('hidden');$("#Bezorging-2-container").addClass('hidden');` and within the if statement they should simply be removed. The `class="hidden"` property is mainly for initializing these elements on hidden before doing anything with the radio input. You'd simply replace two seperate id's with one class, which for readability is right I think.